# How to find x' and x'' using the finite difference approximation of the derivatives?

Tags: derivatives

I need to realize the modified Newton's method to find the minimum of my function. I have a block-schema of that method:
[image: Modified Newton's method]
But my task requires to I used the finite difference approximation of the derivatives to find $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$. I am trying to get how to find the derivatives from [here](https://studopedia.su/1_16076_konechno-raznostnie-approksimatsii-proizvodnih.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method). But my math level is awful really and the first is too hard for me. From the second article I got that:
$$f'(x) \approx {f(x + h) - f(x) \over h}$$
Is it right? But what's $h$ in my case, $ε$?
How can I find $f''(x)$ from Taylor?
$$f''(x) \approx 2*({f(x + ε) - f(x) \over ε^2} - {f'(x) \over ε})$$
Am I right? The problem is that it requires $f'(x)$ but if I will put an approximation of $f'(x)$ my $f''(x)$ will be zero.

Comment: In your flowchart, $\epsilon$ is meant to be a small number. For an exact minimum, it should be exactly zero, but you need to decide some threshold where it is close enough for your purposes.

Comment: I know that is an epsilon. I mean should I use it like $h$ in my formula? And how to find $f''(x)$ not knowing an accurate value of $f'(x)$?

Comment: The h in the formulas is a step size for the numerical derivatives, so it is different from epsilon. You can try one of these formulas for the finite difference: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient

Comment: @Tyberius, thank you very much!